# How to make my local spark that i have modified as dependency in maven

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I have modified the core of Spark and I added a library 
to execute tasks in gpu but i want to compile some tests 
with maven .How can make this local modified spark as dependency
to compile my tests scala files with maven

Comment: Please, add more information about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give local repository in pom.

```
<repository>
    <id>in-project</id>
    <name>In Project Repo</name>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/library</url>
</repository>
```